# How to configure Delay timing in celery?

Tags: celery

input:

```
>>> from registration import tasks
>>> tasks.mail.delay()
<AsyncResult: 36a2e61c-493b-472c-99f1-cb2391110aa9>
>>> r=tasks.mail.delay()
>>> r.ready()
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 174, in ready
        return self.state in self.backend.READY_STATES
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 277, in state
        return self.backend.get_status(self.id)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 487, in _is_disabled
        raise NotImplementedError('No result backend configured.  '
    NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information.
```

How can i configure the back end so taht i can fix specific period of delay

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are looking to specify the time for when a task should run, you don't need a result backend for that, you have to use the .apply_async method that delay is a shortcut for: `tasks.mail.apply_async(countdown=3)` See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A result backend can be configured via CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND setting if you use celeryconfig.py configuration module

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="amqp"
```

or via Celery instance

```
celery = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')
```

Please check out the [docs](http://celery.github.com/celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) for more info.